# spotify playlist items sorting mechanism in web api

Tags: api, sorting, spotify, playlist

It would be so great if the playlist items endpoint would have a sorting function, like sorting by date added (desc/asc) or other fields. sadly I do not find anything about sorting in the official docs.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-playlists-tracks

does anybody had the same issue as well and how do you solved it?

Comment: I have the same issue as you.
Seems that Spotify has 2 APIs : 
- one PUBLIC (`api.spotify.com/v1`)
- one PRIVATE (`api-partner.spotify.com/pathfinder/v1/query`)

The PRIVATE one can give the result you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder playlists using the *Update Playlist Items* endpoint.

It is a PUT on `/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks` and has some body fields that are required.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/reorder-or-replace-playlists-tracks

Comment: Unfortunately when I've tried using it, the response comes back 200 with a snapshot ID for the playlist but I don't know how to verify it did anything as the order of the playlist in Spotify appears to be the same